# Stop content hiding under nav bar when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right, so I have a basic Jquery script that adds a "fixed" class to the nav bar when the user scrolls past the nav bar (154 pixels down). The issue is, the content below the nav bar then jumps up by 35 pixels (the height of the nav bar). I've tried adding a div class with a padding of 35px that shows when the user scrolls past the nav bar, which, although fixed other display problems, still allowed the content to lift up by 35 pixels. Here's what I have so far:

The jQuery that adds the fixed class, and the jQuery that shows the padding:

```
<script>
var num = 154; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) { 
        $('ul.nav').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('ul.nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
</script>
<script>
var num = 154; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) { 
        $('.padd').show();
    } else {
        $('.padd').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<body ONMOUSEWHEEL="OnMouseWheel()">
    <p><a href="index.html"><img src="images/BannerPicture.png" alt="Leisure in mk logo" width="1024" height="150"></a></p>
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav">
  <a href="index.html"  style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav">
  <a href="centremk.html"  style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%">Centre MK</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav">
  <a href="../music.php"  style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%">Music</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav">
  <a href="../more.php"  style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%">More Stuff</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="pad">
</div>
   <div class="padd">
   </div>
  <div class="Informationbox">
text and shizz
</div>
```

And finally, the CSS:

```
ul.nav {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1024px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #C60;
    font-size: 25px;

}
/* this styles each link when the mouse is NOT hovered over */
li.nav {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:35px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition:.4s;
}
li.nav a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition:.4s;
}
li.nav a:hover {
    line-height: 25px;
    transition:.4s;
}
ul.nav.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.padd {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display:none;
}
.Informationbox {
    background-color: #FF9900;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
        width: 1024px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Try making a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your problem, you will likely get more people willing to help.

Comment: Could you recreate this in on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: add margin-top:35 to the "nav" after block when u scrolles down using jquery

Comment: I'm working on making a JSFiddle, but for some reason, it's not working the way it is in my actual browser tests haha. I'm just looking for a way to keep everything below a certain point below that point. Maybe some padding could help. hmmm

Comment: Wrap your `ul` in a `div` then apply the fixed height to that parent div too, that way, when you change the style of the child `ul` to fixed, the parent container will maintain the positioning of the rest of the elements.

Comment: margin-top doesn't seem to work, sadly :'(

Comment: else use top or padding-top

Comment: I've tried all your suggestions, but they literally seem to do nothing. I'd add a JSFiddle example but it really hates me today :( Oh  well, I'm just gonna play around a little

Comment: It works whilst scrolling with the scrollbar, but using the scroll wheel makes it seem to "jump" more lines than usual

Answer (score 0):

add top 35px to the "nav" after block when u scrolles down using jquery.. and need to remove it when scrolls top..

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {    
if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) { 
    $('ul.nav').addClass('fixed');
    $('.your_div').css({"top" : "35px"});
} else {
    $('ul.nav').removeClass('fixed');
    $('.your_div').css({"top" : "0px"});
}
});
```